# list the value of a multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

this is my code, data grabs a json response from ajax.
when I do console.debug ...if you click on it to expand this is what it shows:

```
181818
0.10926253687316
303030
0.054454277286136
d8a890
0.091268436578171
d8d8d8
0.22377581120944
f0d8c0
0.3269616519174
```

and this my code:

```
data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(a));

            console.debug("Here is blah: %o", data);

            var myArray = data;
            alert(myArray);
    for (var i=0,  tot=myArray.length; i < tot; i++) {
      console.log(myArray[i]); //"aa", "bb"
    }
```

I am trying to loop through the array and log the pair to the console
something like : 181818 = 0.1092 etc..any ideas/suggestions please?

Comment: What is the point of this line? `data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(a));` You might as well write `data = a`, unless you are actually trying to make a deep copy of `a`.

Comment: a is a json string received by an ajax query

Comment: Then why are you `JSON.stringify()`ing it? At any rate, jQuery will parse the JSON for you in most cases.

Comment: sorry my bad. what do you suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
for (var key in data) {
       console.log(key+" = "+data[key]);
}
```

Remember that data is an object not an array.
So in your php code you can just output an array like this

```
echo json_encode($someArray);
```

Where

```
$someArray[181818] = 0.10926253687316;
```

and so on.
Next you can modify as it according to your needs.